# In Android SQLite, when the number of columns is more, the database size with the same data is higher

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application,

***Configuration 1:***

There is SQLite with 3 Columns as following:
Column1:Image1
Column2:Image2
Column3:Image3~Image4~Image5~Image6~Image7~Image8~Image9~Image10

Where Image3 to Image10 are seperated by `'~'`

***Configuration 2:***

Now, If I assign separate columns for Image4 to Image10 then there would be 10 columns with the same data

***Question:***

The database size of ***Configuration 2*** would be bigger than the database size of ***Configuration 1***

When the number of rows in the database is more then the difference between the sizes is higher and considerable

Why?

Comment: For configuration2 u r having more number of columns with respect to 1st configurations

Comment: What are you trying to ask.Please explain briefly..

Comment: Yes more columns but the same data with just 3 columns, in other words the size of data in the database is the same for both configurations but the size of database is different, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

1) Storing delimited lists in a relational database is [almost always a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/10676716)

2) Spanning the values over columns is marginally better; basically, it makes sense if and only if the number of images per user is *really fixed*, like each and every user has exactly 10 images. Otherwise, you will end up with empty values here and there; and if you ever need to handle more than 10 images per user, then you need to alter the structure of your database, which is not what you want

3) I would warmly recommend having a separate table to store the images of each user in rows (not columns), with a foreign that references the corresponding user in the original table; this is a normalized design for a 1-N relationship that is much more flexible, easy to maintain and query

Of course, there is a storage overhead for adding columns or tables, but the advantages of a normalized approach should largely overcome this.